# ios unable to display images from database

Tags: ios, arrays, sqlite

hey guys i am creating a program which fetches images from database and stores it in array. but after storing them in array i am unable to display them. an exception is raised and when i checked it with breakpoints it gave me exception at a line, here is my code and that line,

```
 data=[MyDatabase new];
    slideImages=[data OpenMyDatabase:@"SELECT pic_name FROM exterior":@"pic_name"];
    [self putImageViewsInScrollView:slideImages.count];
       self.FullScreenImageScroller.delegate=self;



}


-(void) putImageViewsInScrollView:(int)numberOfImageViews
{

     for(int i=0 ;i< numberOfImageViews; i++)
    {

        UIImageView *fullScreenImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[slideImages objectAtIndex:i]]];
        fullScreenImageView.frame = CGRectMake((WIDTH_OF_IMAGE * i)  , 0, WIDTH_OF_IMAGE, HEIGHT_OF_IMAGE);
        fullScreenImageView.image= [UIImage imageNamed:[slideImages objectAtIndex:i]];
        [self.FullScreenImageScroller addSubview:fullScreenImageView];
    }

    [self.FullScreenImageScroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(WIDTH_OF_SCROLL_PAGE * ([slideImages count]), HEIGHT_OF_IMAGE)];
    [self.FullScreenImageScroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    [self.FullScreenImageScroller scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(WIDTH_OF_IMAGE,0,WIDTH_OF_IMAGE,HEIGHT_OF_IMAGE) animated:NO];

}
```

here is the line of code where breakpoint gives an exception,

```
UIImageView *fullScreenImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[slideImages objectAtIndex:i]]];
```

what should i do now ,do help n thanks in advance...

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: Home[1059:c07] -[FMResultSet length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xaa9aa90

Answer (score 1, accepted):

image are store in database in **NSData** not the **UIImage** so you put **NSData** in database and fetch **NSData** from database and get image from this **NSData**...and store image in databse is not good concept...save image in document folder and save path of image in database...and get image from this path to show....

if you store NSData in database then get image form this line of code by

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:(NSData *)];
```

else if you want this image in your document folder then use this code

Save Image inside App

```
-(void) saveImage:(UIImage *)image withFileName:(NSString *)imageName ofType:(NSString *)extension inDirectory:(NSString *)directoryPath {
    if ([[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"png"]) {
        [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:[directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", imageName, @"png"]] options:NSAtomicWrite error:nil];
    } else if ([[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"jpg"] || [[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"jpeg"]) {
        [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:[directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", imageName, @"jpg"]] options:NSAtomicWrite error:nil];
    } else {
        ALog(@"Image Save Failed\nExtension: (%@) is not recognized, use (PNG/JPG)", extension);
    }
}

and save this image path in database
```

first this path from databse and then use this code

Get Image From URL

```
-(UIImage *) getImageFromURL:(NSString *)fileURL {
    UIImage * result;

    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fileURL]];
    result = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    return result;
}
```

Insert image into SQLite:

```
sqlite3_bind_blob(compiledStatement,i, [image_data bytes], [image_data length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

and Get image from SQLite:

```
NSData *dataForCachedImage = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(compiledStatement, i) length: sqlite3_column_bytes(compiledStatement, i)];           
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:dataForCachedImage];
```

Comment: how NSDATA can be stored in database ? because i want access images from database only

Comment: you modifying your code to get the data of your pic...its you know how to modifying your code to your requirement...

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not retaining `slideImages`. If you are populating correct UIImage objects, retain the array `slideImages`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you store NSData type in slideImages.
In this case, you should use `[UIImage imageWithData:(NSData *)]` to initialize image object.